# date picker is not initializing angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to intialize the date picker to the textbox using angular JS directive.

Here is my angular JS  directive

```
 var testapp = angular.module('testApp',[]);
 testapp.directive('mydatepicker', function () {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       require: 'ngModel',
       link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        $(element).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'DD, d  MM, yy',
        onSelect: function (date) {
            scope.date = date;
            scope.$apply();
         }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

HTML code I wrote :

```
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="myController">
 // some other html code 
 <input type="text" ng-model="date" mydatepicker />
   <br/>
    {{ date }}
//some other html code
</body>
```

Datepicker is not getting intialized.  Here is the JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5ua9guee/19/

In the JS Fiddle I am getting two errors :

1. Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
2. Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App due to:

I tried the existing posts but no one worked for me.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited your fiddle a bit. It works.

https://jsfiddle.net/dm5pyfbe/

In your code the controller is missing.

```
testApp.controller('myController', function($scope){});
```

Answer (score 0):

It shows you problem:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Then insert your jquery to src;

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```